# Cycles -- Why are my renders so blurry?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blur, noise-reduction

[image: **enter image description here**]

My renders are coming out extremely blurry and weird looking, im still pretty new to blender and im not sure how to fix this issue, and whenever I put the samples to higher numbers like 5000 the render says it will take 160 hours to complete.

Comment: Send the scene file please.

Comment: Looks like Denoise is enabled and is blurring quite much of the scene

Comment: Looks like low resolution and hi AA samples from the picture but the answer above could be also right - could You please share that .blend? Looks like following the Andrew Prices corridor tutorial?

Comment: Welcome, Alfonso Torres. To upload your file use this link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/